# MapBox zoom behavior to zoom about a fixed point

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, mapbox

In a default MapView the view zooms into a point near the coordinate where a user pinches.  I want the pinching to zoom the view in/out of a fixed point.

I could not find any properties or functions in the SDK that seemed to do this.  I implemented my own hack by setting zoomEnabled to false, adding a pinchGesture and letting its velocity (whether positive or negative) to either increase or decrease the zoom level.  However, this naive approach is finicky in effect.

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: Could add what your code looks like to see if it is a coding error?

Comment: no, this is not a coding error.  I simply don't see any capabilities for MapBox to do this.  As far as my own pinch-to-zoom implementation, its very basic.  I don't think implementing  your own gestures is the way to go which is why I'm asking about the MapBox SDK.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the attributes for the MapBox?

Comment: If you post a picture it could help us see what keeps zooming into the object in focus

Comment: I stated the issue clearly.  MapBox's map view will zoom into where the person is pinching by default.  It either has a property/function to change this behavior or not.  A picture would have no use in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found you fix. From what i understand is that you do not want users to move from a fixed point that you have set, but you do want to allow them to zoom in and out. A simple attribute should fix this problem. Under the attributes inspector of the map view look for a check box that is title 'scrolling' and uncheck it. This fixe d the problem for me. I have attached an image to help show what to look for.

[image]

Comment: thats not quite right.  I want them to be able to pan around.  However, when they zoom it should zoom in/out of the center point regardless of where they are pinching.

Comment: So you only want them to be able to zoom in on a center a point, nothing else?

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to do that.